# Finding $\sum\limits_{(a,b,c)\in T}\frac{2^a}{3^b+5^c}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Problem**:

Suppose that $T=\{(a,b,c):a,b,c\in \mathbb{N_{+}}\ \text{and a,b,c are sides of a triangle}\}$, then the value of $\sum\limits_{\left(a,b,c\right)\in T}\dfrac{2^a}{3^b+5^c}$ is _____.

Originially the problem worte $3^b\cdot 5^c$, but when it appeared in my homework it became $+$, which was probably a type error.

However, before my teacher informed us of the mistake, I had already worked on this qustion for a long time. Few results can I deduct from.

Since the 'multiply' form is quite easy, could anyone give me some ideas if the infinite series is convergent or not, and what is its limit, in the case of 'add'?

Comment: What is the solution in the multiplicative case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The series does not converge. For every integer $k>1$, $(a,b,c)=(5k-1, 3k, 2k)$ forms a triangle, but the sum of $\frac{2^a}{3^b+5^c}$ over such triangles diverges, since
$$\frac{2^a}{3^b+5^c}=\frac 12\frac{32^k}{27^k+25^k}>\frac14\left(\frac{32}{27}\right)^k$$
does not tend to $0$ as $k\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for your briliant answer. But it should be $>\dfrac{1}{4}...$, I suppose?

Comment: @ThomasPeng Sure. Have updated the $\geq$ to a $>$.